# allow user to enable/disable network interface without root permission

Tags: command-line, networking, 18.04, permissions, netplan

i would like to allow a user without root permission to enable/disable a network interface from the command line, such as:

```
ip link set ens18 down
```

(ubuntu 18.04 with netplan)

i would appreciate any input or help
cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the best way to do this is via proper configuration of sudo. You can specify exact commands that can be run, and you can (if you choose) make it not required to enter a password

You can either use `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d/network_interface`

With content similar to

```
user1 ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/ip link set ens18 down
```

See here: https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html

All the way down at the bottom is an EXAMPLES section, if you don't want to read the whole thing

Comment: Perfect solution for me. i added two lines like the one you suggested (the second with "up" at the end) and i will do this for a whole group instead of a user. Thank you! by the way: i needed to restart the machine so that the effect takes place. is this really needed? when i try to restart the service it says that the unit sudo.service is masked...

Comment: It is not normally required with a standard linux/unix setup. It's a little strange that a reboot was required